# NServiceBus Central Repository

Tags: repository, nservicebus, soa

I am currently researching the possibility of using NServiceBus for one of our applications.  The current application takes large text files and parses the details into a database.  The users perform various operations on the file content, approve the changes, and finally release the updated file.  When the file is released, various other services need to do something with that file data (drop file in ftp folder, email customer, bill customer).

From what I read services should be autonomous and not share data, except via messages.  I like that concept, however in my case I am wondering if it is practical.  Some of these files can contain up to a million records.

So my question is, should each service (operations, billing, emailer) all have their own database and table for storing this file data, and move the data via the DataBus? Or should I be more pragmatic and only send the fileID in the message which references a central file table?

Thanks for any guidance you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that one should not do with a service bus:

- move masses of data
- perform queries
- large ETL operations

You are certainly able to do all these things but you will probably be left disappointed.  The messaging to enable some of these operations is fine, though.  Your idea of sending the `FileID` is definitely the way to go.

As an example: I have previously implemented an e-mail sending service.  This service can send attachments but these can be large.  So instead of including the attachments in the messages I stored the attachments on a shared folder and sent a `SendEMailCommand` message that also included the unique attachment ids that need to be sent with the e-mail.  The e-mail service would then pick up the attachments from the shared folder.  After the service successfully sent the mail an `EMailSentEvent` message would be published.

Comment: I agree with Eben on this a ESB is an integration piece of software not a ETL and business logic/application server. ETL is data integration while a ESB is about application integration. A small but significant difference.